# Error with a Symfony query : Expected Literal, got '"'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, select

I have the following query:

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('u.id, u.username, u.username_canonical, u.email, u.email_canonical, u.last_login, u.name, u.type, u.phone, u.site, u.agency, u.subtype, u.info, u.created_date, u.vip')
            ->from('ContrateAdminBundle:Fosuser', 'u')
            ->where('u.created_date BETWEEN "'.$fromdateaccounts.'" AND "'.$todateaccounts.'" ')                      
            ->getQuery();

$results = $query->getResult();
```

in Symfony to fetch user data, but I got the following error:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 223: Error: Expected Literal, got '"'
500 Internal Server Error - QueryException
1 linked Exception: QueryException »
```

My query output is:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, u.username_canonical, u.email, u.email_canonical, u.last_login, u.name, u.type, u.phone, u.site, u.agency, u.subtype, u.info, u.created_date, u.vip
FROM ContrateAdminBundle:Fosuser u
WHERE u.created_date BETWEEN "2014-08-04 13:29" AND "2014-10-30 13:29"
```

Comment: Have you try with simple quote instead of double quote?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

String literals in SQL are denoted by single quotes `'`, not double quotes `"`, so you have to replace the `"` as string delimiters in your query by `'`:

```
$query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('u.id, u.username, u.username_canonical, u.email, u.email_canonical, u.last_login, u.name, u.type, u.phone, u.site, u.agency, u.subtype, u.info, u.created_date,u.vip')
            ->from('ContrateAdminBundle:Fosuser', 'u')
            ->where('u.created_date BETWEEN \'${fromdateaccounts}\' AND \'{$todateaccounts}\'')                      
            ->getQuery();
```

Answer (score 5):

Please use parameters. Accepted answer could generate SQL injections.

```
    ->where('u.something = ?1')
    ->setParameter(1, '')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Expr :

```
$queryBuilder = $em->createQueryBuilder();

...
->where($queryBuilder->expr()->between('u.created_date', $fromdateaccounts, $todateaccounts));
```